# Make a list of words from given characters

Tags: python, algorithm, cpu-word, combinations

I'm trying to make a list of words from given characters (word) with given length. Each word is a combination of the given characters(word) and [a..z][0..9] (no uppercase)

E.g: Length = 5, given words: out  (given word's length < max length)

The function should return a list that contain: outaa, outba, ..., out9a, out0a, ..., outab, outbb, ..., out9b, out0b, ..., aouta, bouta, ...aaout, baout ...

Meant that we fill the remaining character with [a..z][0..9] with the position of the given word being shifted one at a time.

I'm still thinking about a way to do that but couldn't come up with any ideas yet. Anyone mind giving me a help, please?

Thank you so much

Comment: `Anyone mind giving me a help, please?` -- Sounds like saying: `Anyone mind writing the code for me, please.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce the remaining characters, then cycle the word position with [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to produce all permutations:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

def generate_words(start, length, _chars=ascii_lowercase + digits):
    remainder = length - len(start)
    if remainder < 1:
        yield start
        return
    for letters in product(_chars, repeat=remainder):
        combo = deque(letters + (start,))
        for _ in range(remainder + 1):
            yield ''.join(combo)
            combo.rotate()
```

This is a generator, loop over the output:

```
>>> for word in generate_words('out', 5):
...     print word
... 
aaout
outaa
aouta
about
outab
bouta
acout
outac
couta
adout
outad
douta
aeout
outae
eouta
afout
outaf
# etc.
```

or call `list()` on the generator and be prepared to store a large number of words if the difference between `len(start)` and `length` starts to go beyond 3 (an additional 4 characters produces 8398080 combinations, 5 characters is 362797056 combinations; the formula is `(36**remainder)*(remainder + 1)`).

Comment: He also wants `baout` etc., the word is not necessary at the start...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: there, adjusted to rotate the combo.

Comment: That works for me thanks. Just a little note that its import deque not dequeu, your typo

Comment: just a little follow up, i would like to get a length of the list ('out',4) but I don't think i am doing it the right way. length = len(generated_words('out',4)) or append each item to the list then take the len. Neither way worked for me. How could we take a length of the list in a proper way?

Comment: @Kiddo: this is not a list. This is a generator. You'd have to convert it to a list: `len(list(generated_words('out', 4))`, but that'd be a waste of memory. Just use `sum()` to count the elements instead: `sum(1 for _ in generated_words('out', 4))`.

Comment: @Kiddo: but I already gave you a formula to *calculate* the number of words the generator produces, without having to produce them all. `generated_words('out', 4)` produces 36 * 2, or 72 combos.

Comment: thank for the comment, the purpose of doing this combination is im trying to learn the multi-threading and SSE. Thank you again